# Validation in loop in Php

Tags: php, rest, api, loops, validation

I want to validate many fields in php,so can i validate these fileds using loop in php
right now i am using following code

```
    if(empty($add_data['first_name']))
        {
            $responseJSON = array("Status" => false,"Message" => "please enter first_name");
            header("content-type:application/json");
            $response = json_encode($responseJSON);
            echo $response; 
        }
    elseif(empty($add_data['last_name'])))
        {
            $responseJSON = array("Status" => false,"Message" => "please enter your last_name");
            header("content-type:application/json");
            $response = json_encode($responseJSON);
            echo $response; 
        }
    ...and so on...
```

How can i validate in loop ? Thanks in advance

Comment: store values in an array then use this array in json_encode outside the loop

Comment: are you using core php or you are using any framework like codeigniter or laravel ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an array of fields and their error messages e.g.

```
$fields = array('first_name' => "please enter first_name",
                'last_name'  => "please enter your last_name");
```

Then you can loop through this array to check all the values and issue the appropriate error message:

```
foreach ($fields as $field => $error) {
    if(empty($add_data[$field])) {
        $responseJSON = array("Status" => false,"Message" => $error);
        header("content-type:application/json");
        $response = json_encode($responseJSON);
        echo $response; 
    }
}
```